# The difference between web3.version.network and web3.version.ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum, protocol

The return values of the commands `web3.version.network` and `web3.version.ethereum` are:

```
web3.version.network = "The network protocol version"

web3.version.ethereum = "The etherum protocol version."
```

I would like to know the difference between network protocol version and ethereum protocol version and what situations I use in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Since the initial launch, Ethereum has undergone several planned protocol upgrades, which are important changes affecting the underlying functionality and/or incentive structures of the platform.

So, `web3.version.ethereum` returns the current Ethereum protocol version. At present it returns `0x3f` which means 63. So you can know the details of these protocol [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Wire-Protocol#ethereum-sub-protocol).

On other hand, `web3.version.network` returns the current network id which 1 for Mainnet, 3 for Ropsten, 4 for Rinkeby and 42 for Kovan network.

I hope you got the difference between them and can use them as per your usecase.